# Html 5 + css3 two sidebars with three selectors: role v.s class?

Tags: html, css, selector, sidebar, role

I decided to get completely rid of all ids in my CSS and in addition to that I want to begin transition to HTML 5.

Old Markup where .sidebar is the selector for both sidebars and the ID's are uses to style the sidebars individually

```
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar widget-area"></div>
<div id="sidebar-alt" class="sidebar widget-area"></div>
```

now this is what I would do in ***html 4 and I am NOT under the impression that ID's are obsolete in HTML5 please to not upvote this comment I would have done the same in html 4***

```
<div class="sidebar sidebar-primary widget-area"></div>
<div class="sidebar sidebar-secondary widget-area"></div>
```

**My question is now about the role attribute. Is this basically a made up value? Has it or might have some real meaning in the future?**

**Solution 1**
Where .sidebar stays the selector for both sidebars and I would uses aside[role="..."] to style the sidebars individually

```
<aside role="sidebar-primary" class="sidebar widget-area"></aside>
<aside role="sidebar-secondary" class="sidebar widget-area"></aside>
```

**Solution 2**
Or should I better give both sidebars the same role and use the role selector for common styles?

```
<aside role="sidebar" class="sidebar-primary widget-area"></aside>
<aside role="sidebar" class="sidebar-secondary widget-area"></aside>
```

I am not that into HTML 5 yet and I like to get some Opinions what might be better with in depth explanation if possible.

After looking at the `WTC` list of roles the "sidebar" role seems not to be defined and after thing about it both solutions (1+2) might be bad

**Solution 3**
The "complementary" role is defined as a role by W3C so this might be a better way to do it? I am still curious why people come up with role="sidebar" then and what sense does it make to just "invent" roles? If its for `CSS` they should uses classes to style or not?

```
<aside role="complementary" class="sidebar-primary widget-area"></aside>
<aside role="complementary" class="sidebar-secondary widget-area"></aside>
```

Answer (score 5):

`role` is not made up

- here's a really [simple guide](http://www.webteacher.ws/2010/10/14/aria-roles-101/) on how roles work
- you can [style them](http://davidejones.com/blog/577-aria-roles-targeting-css/)
- take a look at [microformats](http://html5doctor.com/microformats/) in general
- read [hardboiled webdesign](http://hardboiledwebdesign.com/) by andy clarke
- [WAI-ARIA](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/) technical document

Comment: Yes. You may want to include a summary on how roles work, to give the links a little more context.

Comment: Thx, i know i can style them as you can read in the question, i also know that they are not all made up, i should have been more specific. but when i search for "sidebar" on [-this-](http://www.webteacher.ws/2010/10/14/aria-roles-101/) and [-this-](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles) list i found nothing. So "sidebar" seems not to be a existing role. Anyway roles seem to have a lot more predefined values then i taught thx for the links. SO what about roles that are not predefined? Can we just make them up? Does it makes sense to do so? I guess not? Where to find the Sidebar role?